# What is the light bulb in the center of my 2010 Hyundai Elantra Touring headlamp assembly called?

Tags: hyundai, lights, elantra

The dead bulb in question is circled in red.

[image: Headlight picture]

I thought this was the parking light, but every time I asked an autoparts store for a parking light bulb for the same bulb on the passenger side they directed me to the orange light bulbs for blinkers.

I eventually managed to buy one that fits. However, now the driver's side one is dead. I'd like to look into LED replacements. Since those will be ordered online, and don't look like the current bulbs at all I want to make sure I know what the bulb is called before I order it.

Comment: Any chance you can post a photo of the bulb itself? There's several different sorts that are often used for multiple applications. They tend to be defined by size and pin layout rather than useage

Answer (score 2):

According to the Hyundai website, that is the low beam (#5 below). This image is looking at the back of the headlight assembly.

[image]

Source: http://www.hemanual.org/head_lamps_components_and_components_location-2227.html

Comment: This doesn;'t seem to match mine. I'll take the lense out  and take more picture later. The big lens (innermost towards grill) definitely has two bulbs on one top of the other.

Comment: Have you owned this car from new? Have the headlight assemblies been replaced? Also, depending where you live, some countries have strict requirements on headlights and the OEMs adjust accordingly.

Comment: Yes it was the low beam, but no that's not my  headlight assembly. I have a hatchback which takes an H11B low beam, which has two prong, but no. Most 2011 Hyundai Elantra's take a H11 low beam like in that picture. Anyway, I'm adept enough at removing the lens assembly at this point to match flat rate estimates, I'm just going to remove dead bulbs and take them into the store.

Answer (score 0):

The bulb was low beam, the type is H11B Most 2011 elantra's have a H11 Bulb as show in [CharlesRB's answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/52295/35963). Mine was different.